# (ObjC) Unable to add libraries-Help please

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import, readline

I'm following an objC book and I need to use readline() to obtain a string.

However, before I can even get to that, I need to add the library that contains it. Therefore, I go into Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Press the + ->Search and Add addlibreadline.dylib

After I do this, I have an icon under my top-level item that has the name of this library. BUT when I go into my code in main.m, NOTHING is imported. There is no #import

WHY? I have tried different things for hours and am frustrated!

Am I not understanding something about importing and libraries?

Btw: I am using Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a) and Yosemite 10.10.1 (14B25)

Thank you,

Comment: Did you mean libreadline.dylib?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got the libraries linked, try adding this:

`#import <readline/readline.h>`

Then you should be able to use readline().

http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=148&t=7617

Comment: Why do I need to add that myself, what does linking a library even do then? In the future, if I add another library, how will I know what the import statement is?